# Using Graph API is it possible to get the password back for an Application?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Using the REST or C# API can I get the password value in `PasswordCredentials` back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The `value` of a [`PasswordCredential`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#passwordcredential-type) entry for an [`Application`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#application-entity) or [`ServicePrincipal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#serviceprincipal-entity) can only be written.